# What does mastered mean on a commercial library?

Tags: effects, library, mastering

All the libraries I have bought/seen advertised say mastered at 24/96. Is this meaning simply that the audio was cleaned up, metadata was added and its ready for drag and drop use? Or is there something more?

Answer (score 2):

In that context I tend to read "mastered" as audio that is edited, problems eq'd out, strange noises removed, etc.  Sometimes that can also imply downsampling from a higher sample rate.

I don't tend to read that as having anything to do with metadata.

I also don't take that to imply any sort of dynamics processing.

YMMV

Answer (score 0):

While I've never used that term to describe my own libraries, I'd assume it just means it was produced, edited, processed etc at 24/96. It's a strange choice of words, as it obviously causes a bit of confusion. I always just say "24 bit audio" in the specs, 24/44 lately.